# Passing Javascript combobox select value into a java method

Tags: javascript, java

I want to pass a selected value of a combobox into a java Method. All the posts I see refer about using HttpServletRequest and getParameter function to pass the value, but my problem is, I need the value as a string passed into a Java Method, that already exists. Any pointers how to do it? 
I have seen some references of doPost method, but that really doesn't help me, as all I need is the value passed into a customized java method and use it. Any help would be deeply appreciated. I'm stuck on this for several hours.

Any clarification or extra information required, please let me know.

```
<SCRIPT>
function sendParam(){
  var item=   document.Form.item[document.Form.item.selectedIndex].value
  //I need to send this value to the server side java code and process further
 }
 </SCRIPT>
```

Comment: What server are you running? Can you show us some code? What have you tried, and what is the context of server side javascript and Java code. If the problem is server side and javascript is not used there you may need to remove the `javascript` question tag.

Comment: Hi Traktor53, I'm running the code on OC4j server. Let me explain. I have a jsp file that contains all client side stuff, like combo boxes, buttons and others. I need to pass the selected index of one of the combo-boxes(as this info won't be available to the server during user selection, I'm using javaScript to get the selected value, and pass it back to the server for further processing though a java method and retrieve the of result).  I'll edit and post the sample code for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I got it working using the action class. I have posted my answer below. Thanks for the response. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it through action class.

```
<SCRIPT>
function sendParam(){
var item=   document.Form.item[document.Form.item.selectedIndex].value
//I need to send this value to the server side java code and process further
var url = "/urlToActionClass"
document.Form.acton = url;
document.Form.submit();
}
</SCRIPT>
```

now the value is passed into java which I read in the action class and used it in the required Java function.